# Why this change gives different results in Integrate?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics, code-review

I'm new in Mathematica and can't understand why changing a number from Real to Integer is giving different results in my equations:

```
Integrate[(2.0/0.2)*Exp[-3.14*1.85*(10.0 - x)/0.2^2], {x, 0., 10.}]
0.

Integrate[10*Exp[-3.14*1.85*(10.0 - y)/0.2^2], {y, 0.0, 10.0}]
0.0688586675848
```

The numerical integration results the correct value:

```
NIntegrate[(2.0/0.2)*Exp[-3.14*1.85*(10.0 - z)/0.2^2], {z, 0., 10.}]
0.0688587
```

This also accurs when just adding the point for a Real number:

```
Integrate[10.*Exp[-3.14*1.85*(10.0 - y)/0.2^2], {y, 0.0, 10.0}]
0.

Integrate[10*Exp[-3.14*1.85*(10.0 - y)/0.2^2], {y, 0.0, 10.0}]
0.0688586675848
```

Anyone may explain why is this occurring?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is strange that this should happen, but note that integrating a Gaussian with a huge prefactor on the x^2 is a big problem, because the exponential decays *extremely* fast, making for a tough numerical problem.  (Better to integrate with exact value: `Integrate[(2.0/0.2)*Exp[-3.14*1.85*(10.0 - x)/0.2^2] // 
  Rationalize, {x, 0., 10.}]`.) In any case, there is something different in the way that *Mathematica* preprocesses the expression that makes this strange thing occur.

Comment: ... and using `NIntegrate` is even better if you seek a numerical answer. `Integrate` is best suited to finding *analytical* answers. `NIntegrate` is better suited for numerics, and you will be able to set things like `WorkingPrecision` and `AccuracyGoal` etc. For instance `NIntegrate[10.*Exp[-3.14*1.85*(10.0 - y)/0.2^2], {y, 0.0, 10.0}]` returns the correct result directly.

Comment: This works: Integrate[(2.0/0.2)*Exp[-3.14*1.85*(10.0 - x)/0.2^2], {x, 0., 0.01, 
  10.}]

Comment: as does this : Integrate[(2.0/0.2)*Exp[-3.14*1.85*(10.0 - x)/0.2^2] // 
   Rationalize[#, 0.00001] &, {x, 0, 10}] // N

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, guys.

I thought I was missing something too obvious as a newbie in Mathematica.

@chris, is this "{x, 0., 0.01, 10.}" breaking the integration interval into two parts or is it something else?

Comment: @edo   Yes it's breaking the integration

Answer (score 2):

`Integrate` may use transformations that are not numerically stable.  In this case, it uses `Simplify`, which I suspect factors out the constant term in the exponential, $e^{k+ax}=e^ke^{ax}$.  Actually, `Simplify` seems to do this in a clever way, $c\,e^{-k+ax}=(c/e^k)\,e^{ax}$.  The $e^k$ factor overflows and is automatically converted to arbitrary precision.
I say "cleverly" because if $c$ were an exact number, this would avoid underflow.  Unfortunately, multiplying by the machine-precision $c = 10.$ causes a (silenced) machine underflow, which results in zero:

```
Simplify[(2.0/0.2)*Exp[-3.14*1.85*(10.0 - x)/0.2^2]]
(*  0.  *)
```

When $c = 10$ is exact (or arbitrary-precision), we get no underflow:

```
Simplify[10*Exp[-3.14*1.85*(10.0 - x)/0.2^2]]
(*  1.976235315927*10^-630 E^(145.225 x)  *)
```

Moral: *It's best to `Rationalize[]` your coefficients when using an exact solver like `Integrate[]`.*

---

Here's how to see it inside `Integrate`:

```
Trace[
 Integrate[10.*Exp[-3.14*1.85*(10.0 - y)/0.2^2], {y, 0.0, 10.0}],
 call : Simplify[e_ /; ! FreeQ[e, Power], ___] :> 
  HoldForm[call] -> call,
 TraceInternal -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]