# Speed up FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

I need to calculate `Sv[zm,zs,zh]` for a given range of `zm` and `zs` with fixed `zh`. I have written a code where `zm` is a function of `zs` given by `zmzs[zs, zh, tb, zmmin, zmmax]` so that `Sv[zm(zs),zs,zh] = Sv[zmzs[zs, zh, tb, zmmin, zmmax],zs,zh]` and now I only need to give the range of `zs` only. To add, `zh` and `tb` are given constants, `zmmin` and `zmmax` are the min and max of the range in `FindRoot` in `zmzs[zs, zh, tb, zmmin, zmmax]`.

```
d = 3;
ag = 10;
pg = 10;
wp = 20;
f[z_, zh_] := 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1);
tzsint[z_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{zr, zsr, zhr}, {zr, zsr, zhr} = Rationalize[{z, zs, zh}, 0]; zr^d/Sqrt[f[zr, zhr] (zsr^(2 d) - zr^(2 d))]]
tzs[zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{zsr, zhr}, {zsr, zhr} = Rationalize[{zs, zh}, 0]; NIntegrate[tzsint[z, zsr, zhr], {z, 0, zsr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 20]]
tzmint[z_?NumericQ, zm_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{zr, zmr, zhr}, {zr, zmr, zhr} = Rationalize[{z, zm, zh}, 0]; -1/(f[zr, zhr] Sqrt[1 - (zmr^(2 d) f[zr, zhr])/(z^(2 d) f[zmr, zhr])])]
tzm[zm_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{zmr, zhr}, {zmr, zhr} = Rationalize[{zm, zh}, 0]; NIntegrate[tzmint[z, zmr, zhr], {z, 0, zhr, zmr}, Method -> PrincipalValue, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 20]]
Svint1[z_?NumericQ, zm_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{zr, zmr, zhr}, {zr, zmr, zhr} = Rationalize[{z, zm, zh}, 0]; zmr^d/(zr^d Sqrt[f[zr, zhr] zmr^(2 d) - f[zmr, zhr] zr^(2 d)])]
Svint2[z_?NumericQ, zm_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{zr, zmr, zsr, zhr}, {zr, zmr, zsr, zhr} = Rationalize[{z, zm, zs, zh}, 0]; (((zsr^(2 d) zmr^(2 d) zr)/zhr^(d + 1)) + (zr^d (zsr^(2 d) f[zmr, zhr] - zmr^(2 d))))/((zmr^d Sqrt[zsr^(2 d) - zr^(2 d) ] + zsr^d Sqrt[zmr^(2 d) f[zr, zhr] - zr^(2 d) f[zmr, zhr]]) Sqrt[(zmr^(2 d) f[zr, zhr] - zr^(2 d) f[zmr, zhr]) (zsr^(2 d) - zr^(2 d))])]
Sv[zm_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{zmr, zsr, zhr}, {zmr, zsr, zhr} = Rationalize[{zm, zs, zh}, 0]; NIntegrate[Svint1[z, zmr, zhr], {z, zsr, zmr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 20] + NIntegrate[Svint2[z, zmr, zsr, zhr], {z, 0, zsr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 20]]
tzmzs[zm_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ, tb_?NumericQ] := Module[{zmr, zsr, zhr, tbr}, {zmr, zsr, zhr, tbr} = Rationalize[{zm, zs, zh, tb}, 0]; NIntegrate[tzmint[z, zmr, zhr], {z, 0, zhr, zmr}, Method -> PrincipalValue, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 20] - NIntegrate[tzsint[z, zsr, zhr], {z, 0, zsr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 20] - tbr]
zmzs[zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ, tb_?NumericQ, zmmin_?NumericQ, zmmax_?NumericQ] := zm /. FindRoot[tzmzs[zm, zs, zh, tb] == 0, {zm, zmmin, zmmax}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 20]
zszm[zm_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ, tb_?NumericQ, zsmin_?NumericQ, zsmax_?NumericQ] := zs /. FindRoot[tzmzs[zm, zs, zh, tb] == 0, {zs, zsmin, zsmax}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 20]
```

The issue is calculating `zmzs[zs, zh, tb, zmmin, zmmax]` takes a lot of time, for example I evaluated everything at `zs=9.9952388099`. `zmzs[zs, zh, tb, zmmin, zmmax]` takes around 13 secs to calculate, `Sv[zmzs[zs, zh, tb, zmmin, zmmax],zs,zh]` takes 15 secs to calculate. Using the value of `zm=13.127957300691564691` calculated from `zmzs[zs, zh, tb, zmmin, zmmax]` and plugging it directly to `Sv[zm,zs,zh]` takes only around 2 secs. This means that `Sv` itself calculates fairly quick, it is really `zmzs[zs, zh, tb, zmmin, zmmax]` that takes quite some time.

In the end I want to plot `Sv` for `[zs,1.5,9.9952388097]` which will definitely take a lot of time, in fact I tried plotting it and it has already been 4 hrs but so far no result yet!!!

```
zmzs[9.9952388099, 10, 0.100000100000003174, 10.00099982369714445, 13.1279573]//AbsoluteTiming
{13.1723073, 13.127957300691564691}

Sv[zmzs[9.9952388099, 10, 0.100000100000003174, 10.00099982369714445, 13.1279573], 9.9952388099, 10]//Chop//AbsoluteTiming
{15.0956025, 0.010820232314756221363}

Sv[13.127957300691564691, 9.9952388099, 10]//Chop//AbsoluteTiming
{1.9989049, 0.010820232314756221363}
```

Is there any way to speed up the code in order to plot out `Sv` in a shorter amount of time?

Comment: How fast is it if you get rid of all the Rationalize and all the non-machine-precision calculations? Then all the calculations should run with your CPU hardware floating point and perhaps be substantially faster. Then how fast is it if instead of Plot your use `ListPlot[..,Joined->True]` and calculate just enough points for that to be able to see the behavior without needing to have Plot calculate every single pixel.

Comment: Can you add equations you are trying compute. It seems you do multiple numerical integrations using `WorkingPrecision` above the standard value. It would be nice to know why.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

d = 3;
ag = 10;
pg = 10;
wp = 20;

SetOptions[NIntegrate,
  AccuracyGoal -> ag,
  PrecisionGoal -> pg,
  WorkingPrecision -> wp,
  MaxRecursion -> 20];

SetOptions[FindRoot,
  AccuracyGoal -> ag,
  PrecisionGoal -> pg,
  WorkingPrecision -> wp];

f[z_, zh_] := 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1);
```

It is only necessary to restrict a function to numeric arguments if the function makes use of a numeric technique.

```
tzsint[z_, zs_, zh_] = z^d/Sqrt[f[z, zh] (zs^(2 d) - z^(2 d))];

tzs[zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] :=
 Module[{zsr, zhr},
  {zsr, zhr} = Rationalize[{zs, zh}, 0];
  NIntegrate[tzsint[z, zsr, zhr], {z, 0, zsr}]]
```

Complicated calculations that do not use numeric techniques should be done once ([`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) vice [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) or use [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) on RHS of `SetDelayed`) and use [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) to help `improve efficiency` (**EDIT**) by reducing the number of individual operations.

```
tzmint[z_, zm_, zh_] =
  -1/(f[z, zh] Sqrt[1 - (zm^(2 d) f[z, zh])/(z^(2 d) f[zm, zh])]) //
   Simplify;

tzm[zm_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] :=
 Module[{zmr, zhr},
  {zmr, zhr} = Rationalize[{zm, zh}, 0];
  NIntegrate[tzmint[z, zmr, zhr], {z, 0, zhr, zmr},
   Method -> PrincipalValue]]

Svint1[z_, zm_, zh_] =
  zm^d/(z^d Sqrt[f[z, zh] zm^(2 d) - f[zm, zh] z^(2 d)]) //
   Simplify;

Svint2[z_, zm_, zs_, zh_] =
  (((zs^(2 d) zm^(2 d) z)/zh^(d + 1)) + (z^d (zs^(2 d) f[zm, zh] - zm^(2 d))))/
    ((zm^d Sqrt[zs^(2 d) - z^(2 d)] + 
        zs^d Sqrt[
          zm^(2 d) f[z, zh] - z^(2 d) f[zm, zh]]) Sqrt[(zm^(2 d) f[z, zh] - 
          z^(2 d) f[zm, zh]) (zs^(2 d) - z^(2 d))]) //
   Simplify;

Sv[zm_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] :=
 Module[{zmr, zsr, zhr},
  {zmr, zsr, zhr} = Rationalize[{zm, zs, zh}, 0];
  NIntegrate[Svint1[z, zmr, zhr], {z, zsr, zmr}] +
   NIntegrate[Svint2[z, zmr, zsr, zhr], {z, 0, zsr}]]

tzmzs[zm_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ, tb_?NumericQ] :=
 Module[{zmr, zsr, zhr, tbr},
  {zmr, zsr, zhr, tbr} = Rationalize[{zm, zs, zh, tb}, 0];
  NIntegrate[tzmint[z, zmr, zhr], {z, 0, zhr, zmr},
    Method -> PrincipalValue] -
   NIntegrate[tzsint[z, zsr, zhr], {z, 0, zsr}] - tbr]

zmzs[zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ, tb_?NumericQ, zmmin_?NumericQ, 
  zmmax_?NumericQ] :=
 zm /. FindRoot[tzmzs[zm, zs, zh, tb] == 0,
   {zm, zmmin, zmmax}]

zszm[zm_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ, tb_?NumericQ, zsmin_?NumericQ, 
  zsmax_?NumericQ] :=
 zs /. FindRoot[tzmzs[zm, zs, zh, tb] == 0,
   {zs, zsmin, zsmax}]
```

Checking the timing

```
zmzs[9.9952388099, 10, 0.100000100000003174, 10.00099982369714445, 
  13.1279573] //
 AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.272723, 13.127957300691564608} *)

Sv[zmzs[9.9952388099, 10, 0.100000100000003174, 10.00099982369714445, 
    13.1279573], 9.9952388099, 10] // Chop // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.276597, 0.0108202323147562170881} *)

Sv[13.127957300691564691, 9.9952388099, 10] // Chop // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.015935, 0.010820232314756221330} *)
```

You did not indicate the range of interest for `zs` for the plot

```
Plot[
   Sv[zs, 1.5, 9.9952388097],
   {zs, 3/2, 15},
   PlotRange -> All,
   PlotPoints -> 50,
   MaxRecursion -> 5,
   ImageSize -> 400] //
  AbsoluteTiming //
 Column
```

[image]

Comment: Re "use `Simplify` to help preserve precision by reducing the number of individual operations": Error propagation is not a concern of `Simplify`, which is mainly concerned with reducing the number of leaves of the expression. I don't know how often — I would guess not very — but it sometimes makes the error much worse.  But overall, +1. Just didn't want others to think `Simplify` can be relied on in this way.

Comment: Example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/236767 -- as I said, I expect this is a rare case, but `Simplify` makes no attempt to avoid underflow or subtractive cancellation.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - Thanks. Corrected.